# Is there a way I can still use app_offline.htm on my ASP.NET MVC 2 projects? If not, is there an alternative method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, app-offline.htm

I loved the features of using app_offline.htm on my ASP.NET WebForm based sites.
Upload the file and your app is immediately "offline".  Snappy.

Now that I'm using MVC 2, I noticed that this no longer works.
Is there a way to get this behavior in ASP.NET MVC 2 like it did in WebForms?
If not, what alternative do you prefer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

app_offline.htm works on MVC sites. You need to make sure it's 512 bytes or larger.  I use it all the time when updating a couple of MVC sites.

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid, because suddenly it's working for me!  I did, however, notice that none of my content gets rendered (Images, etc...)

They all reside in either my /Content folder or /Scripts folder.

Comment: LOL, welcome to the club. Been there, done that, sure to do it again.

Comment: In order to get images to render in the App_Offline.htm page, you need to [embed the image within the html](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter).